# Google OAuth doesn't work in chrome extension created with Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I have a problem with Google OAuth when using it in a chrome extension created with Angular.

To be more obvious, I'm going to explain my issue step by step:

1. I've developed a complex Angular app and want to use it inside a chrome extension
2. I've created an empty chrome extension that is going to show the Angular project inside an iframe that is in the chrome extension (there isn't any popup for this extension)
3. How is this extension going to work? when users are searching and visiting websites, based on the specific condition an iframe that contains an Angular project (the iframe created inside the extension codes) will open. let's see my extension project structure:

[image]

4. This is the result:

[image]

## My issue:

When I serve the Angular app in my localhost:4200 the Google OAuth and Facebook Auth work very well (Google or Facebook auth popup opens very well when clicking on the "signup with Google" or "sign up with Facebook").
But when I deploy my Angular app inside the extension (The Angular app opens in an iframe inside the chrome extension as you can see in the above picture) the Google OAuth and Facebook Auth don't work (don't open Google or Facebook auth popup when clicking on the "signup with Google" or "sign up with Facebook").

**Note:** I use [@abacritt/angularx-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login) for Google and Facebook Auth in the Angular app

Any solution or point would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please define **Google OAuth and Facebook Auth don't work.**  Unfortunately  **Don't work** does not properly define the issue please read [ask] and include [example]

Comment: @DalmTo, I updated the question and explain more about "Don't work"